# how can i search joined tables on non primary key column

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables product_inflow and pricelist

**> product_inflow Table = (Id,ItemDescription,QuantityIn,date)

> pricelist Table = ( productinflow_Id[foreign key as primary
>   key],WareHousPrice,WareHouseCustomer,RetailPrice,WitholdPrice )**

i wrote an inner join query to join both tables and display in a j table .Now i want to be able search through the joined tables via a text field using the key released event method...The problem is when i search using a particular Id it returns the correct row result but when i try with the item Description it returns neither results or error messages...
Is there a way i can optimize my query to be able to use the key pressed event and display the matching item description  in a j table as i type or do i have to create a new table all together and dump the info in manually to display them in the table with the key released event method in case the data items are too many and typing in full may be inconvenient for the users??

this is my code behind the searchfield key released method

```
 con = DBConnection.getConnection();
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql;
        sql = " select  productinflow.Id,productinflow.ItemDescription,pricelist.WareHousePrice,pricelist.WareHouseCustomer,"
                + "pricelist.RetailPrice,pricelist.WithHoldPrice"
                + " from"
                + " finaladatdb.productinflow inner join  pricelist"
                + " on productinflow.Id=pricelist.productInflow_Id  where productinflow.ItemDescription like'"+searchfield3.getText()+"%'";  

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       CustomerTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

im using innoDB...Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You also should be careful when tagging. mysql is not the same thing as sql server. Since you stated you are using innodb I assume you must be using mysql.